# Date/time conversion using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I would like to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) for date conversion.

Here's what I want:

```
var original_format = "Tuesday, May 22, 2012";

var output1 = "16 hours ago"
var output2 = "2012-05-22T00:00:00+02:00"
```

For the output1 no problem, for the second-one would it be possible to make it using moment.js?

```
moment("original_format").fromNow(); // "16 hours ago"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
moment("original_format").format();
```